# Как отслеживать клонированную кнопку?

Tags: javascript

У менять есть блок, который клонируется и вставляется в 2 места, но клонированный блок ни как не кликается, а помимо клика, мне нужно чтоб они вместе становились активными, как это можно сделать?

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.input');
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
const ul = document.querySelector('.ul');
const mainUl = document.querySelector('.main-ul');


button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('wrap')

  div.innerHTML = 
    `
    <button class="btn"></button>
    <p></p>
    `
  
  const btn = div.querySelector('.btn')
  const p = div.querySelector('p')
  
  p.textContent = input.value;
  
  ul.appendChild(div)
  
  const cloneDiv = div.cloneNode(true)
  mainUl.appendChild(cloneDiv)
  
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    btn.classList.toggle('btn--active')
  })
})
```

```css
.wrap {
  min-width: 400px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

p {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.btn {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #4DD599;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn--active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-ul">
  <h1>Main</h1>
</ul>
<ul class="ul">
  <h2>Ul</h2>
</ul>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="input" type="text">
  <button class="button">Создать</button>
</div>
```

Comment: навешивай обработчик до клонирования

Comment: В документации сказано: Клонирование узлов копирует все атрибуты и их значения, в том числе собственных (в линию) перехватчиков. Это не копирует перехватчики событий, добавленных используя addEventListener() или тех что назначены через свойства элемента (т.е node.onclick = fn). Поэтому не понятно за что минусанули мой ответ.

Comment: @DaniilLoban: сегодня здесь раздача минусов, как я понял :)

Comment: @UModeL хорошо то что хорошо заканчивается)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задействуйте [делегирование](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation). И вместо `innerHTML`, рекомендую использовать `insertAdjacentHTML`, а также, вставляйте переменные непосредственно в [шаблонные литералы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Можете добавлять сколько угодно списков - в каждый из них добавится необходимая разметка и логика будет отрабатывать, как задумано. При этом в скрипте ничего менять на потребуется.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.input');
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const template =
    `<div class="wrap">
    <button class="btn" group="${input.value}"></button>
    <p>${input.value}</p>
    </div>`;
  document.querySelectorAll('ul').forEach(el => el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template));
});

container.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  if (!ev.target.classList.contains('btn')) return
  document.querySelectorAll(`[group="${ev.target.getAttribute('group')}"].btn`).forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('btn--active'));
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  min-width: 400px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

p { max-width: 200px; }

.btn {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #4DD599;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn--active { background: red; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="main-ul">
    <h1>Main</h1>
  </ul>
  <ul class="ul">
    <h2>Ul</h2>
  </ul>
  <ul class="more-ul">
    <h2>More</h2>
  </ul>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input class="input" type="text">
    <button class="button">Создать</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Поясните за минус :-/

Comment: Кто то всем поставил минус :/
Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример через делегирование событий, таким образом экономится еще и память. Для того чтобы обрабатывать элементы **одновременно**, вовсе не достаточно клонирования, для этой цели можно использовать дата аттрибуты по которым **идентифицировать пары**, в данном случае у меня просто индексирование пар от нуля.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.input');
const button = document.querySelector('.button');

const ul = document.querySelector('.ul');
const mainUl = document.querySelector('.main-ul');

let index = 0

function toggleClass(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "button"){

    // выбираем все кнопки с одним дата аттрибутом
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-id='${e.target.dataset.id}']`)

    // проходим по ним в цикле чтобы поменять классы 
    Array.from(buttons).forEach(e =>  e.classList.toggle('btn--active'))
  }
}

ul.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  toggleClass(e)
})

mainUl.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  toggleClass(e)
})

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('wrap')
  div.innerHTML =`
    <button data-id="${index++}" class="btn"></button>
    <p></p>`
  const btn = div.querySelector('.btn')
  const p = div.querySelector('p')
  p.textContent = input.value;
  ul.appendChild(div)
  const cloneDiv = div.cloneNode(true)
  mainUl.appendChild(cloneDiv)
})
```

```css
.wrap {
  min-width: 400px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

p {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.btn {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #4DD599;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn--active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-ul">
  <h1>Main</h1>
</ul>
<ul class="ul">
  <h2>Ul</h2>
</ul>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="input" type="text">
  <button class="button">Создать</button>
</div>
```